# Automatic start-up when electricity goes on?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios

Is there a way to let my Linux Ubuntu PC automatically start up when it gets electricity?

Comment: Check BIOS settings

Answer (score 6):

This is usually done in the BIOS under power settings.
It may be under South Bridge / Chipset.  in AMI it says 'Restore AC power loss' and you can choose "power Off" which is default, or "Power On" or "Last State".

if you choose Last State, the PC will power back on if it was running before power was removed.